# Get most repeated value from column in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hi have something how this.

```
COLUMN_NAME
------------
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
NAME1
NAME1
NAME4
NAME2
```

I want to get the most repeated value from this colum, on this case, NAME4, any can help me? I tried some query functions but I dont understand the correct logic for this :S

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if I'm not mistaken in the above example the most repeated text is "NAME1", since it occurs 3 times.

I'm sure that there is a better solution for the problem, but I only figured out this:

=index(query(A1:B8,"select A,count(B) where B ='' group by A order by count(B) desc",1),2,1)

NOTE: The quotes after B ='' are two simple quotes, not double quotes!! At that point we are comparing the B column with the empty string.

Supposing that:

- The raw data should be in A2:A8 cells (NAME1, NAME2, NAME3, ...)
- There is an "extra" column we use, next to A (column B). All cells should be empty.

The above formula first runs a query (see the QUERY function inside) in which we count the occurences of each text and we are ordering by the count number in descending order. We will get something like this:

**Column_name   count**

**NAME1 3**

**NAME2 2**

**NAME3 1**

**NAME4 1**

Then - with the index function - we get the cell value which is in the 2nd row and 1st column of the result of the query. This will be always good, because we always sort (=order by) the query results in descending order. So the most repeated text will always be in that position.

So it's a workaround, not that pretty, but works.

Hope it helped anyway.